# Global vs local: global density matrix and all the reduced density matrix

Tags: quantum-state, fidelity, state-tomography, correlations, state-preparation

I prepare a $n$-qubit quantum state $\sigma$ whose ideal state is $\rho$, then perform state tomography on all the $m$- qubit reduced states. Ideally, I find that all the $m$- qubit reduced states are the same as the ideal states. Then how can I guarantee the similarity between the noisy state $\sigma$ and ideal state $\rho$?

Comment: Are you asking if you can guarantee that $\rho$ is close to $\sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** In general, it is impossible to assess the similarity of two $n$-qubit states from the knowledge of $m$-qubit reduced states when $m<n$. However, if they are free of $n$-partite entanglement, then we can reconstruct and compare them.

Suppose we wish to prepare
$$
|\text{+GHZ}\rangle=\frac{|0\dots 0\rangle+|1\dots 1\rangle}{\sqrt2}\tag1
$$
but a $Z$ error on one of the qubits turned it into
$$
|\text{-GHZ}\rangle=\frac{|0\dots 0\rangle-|1\dots 1\rangle}{\sqrt2}.\tag2
$$
The fidelity between the two states is zero. However, every $m$-qubit reduced state of $\rho=|\text{+GHZ}\rangle\langle\text{+GHZ}|$ is the maximally mixed state $\frac{I}{2^m}$. The same is true for $\sigma=|\text{-GHZ}\rangle\langle\text{-GHZ}|$. Therefore, we cannot tell them apart just by looking at the results of tomography on any $m$-qubit reduced states. In fact, we can't tell $\rho$ and $\sigma$ from the $n$-qubit maximally mixed state $\frac{I}{2^n}$ either.

That said, there are states for which this task is easy. For example, if $\rho$ is a product state then we can identify it exactly by using $m$-qubit reduced states for any $0<m<n$. More generally, if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are free of $n$-partite entanglement, then we can reconstruct them from the knowledge of all $m$-qubit reduced states and hence we can assess their similarity.

Comment: Suppose we have a 3-qubit density matrix $|xxx\rangle$ and have collapsed the last qubit (measuring 1), then we are left with the partially collapsed state $|xx1\rangle$... Say that we would now like to know the state coefficient for the second qubit $|x?1\rangle$, could we do this by adding $c q_{2=0} = c_1  |001\rangle + c_2 |101\rangle$ and $c q_{2=1} = c_3  |011\rangle + c_4 |111\rangle$ directly from the full/uncollapsed density matrix, then renormalizing the probability back to 1?